Authorization issue
<response>
<message>The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources./message>
<parameters>
<resources>Magento_Customer::customer</resources>
</parameters>
</response>

I am getting this issue  when  trying to fetch the customers from magento2.3.why.how to solve

The error indicates that the API consumer (the user or application) does not have the required authorization to access the Magento_Customer::customer resource. This usually happens when the proper permissions are not granted to the integration token or API user.
Can you check the permission?
